# bash echo stars or hashes based on a specific number

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I would like to know how can I echo the same number of # or * based of a number I type?

For example.

If I type/have **3**, I would like to have as return **###**.

Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like an exercise or homework. Sure you do not wand to find out yourself to learn that stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say:

```
$ num=3
$ printf "%0.s*" $(seq $num)
***
```

And if the number is fixed, use brace expansion `{..}`:

```
$ printf "%0.s*" {1..3}
***
```

Comment: Thank you, Fedorqui for your reply!